# Eliminar aplicación en Heroku

Tags: nodejs, git, heroku

Quiero eliminar un aplicación Heroku desde mi línea de comandos, pero no me deja eliminarla, que puede ser, ¿Qué comandos tengo erróneos?

```
user@2027061402206 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Node/7.1-restserver (master)
$ heroku apps:destroy limitless-basin-90960

 !    WARNING: This will delete limitless-basin-90960 including all add-ons.
 !    To proceed, type limitless-basin-90960 or re-run this command with
 !    --confirm limitless-basin-90960

   > > heroku apps:destroy confirm limitless-basin-90960
  !    Confirmation did not match limitless-basin-90960. Aborted.
```

Comment: Te lo está diciendo... cuando te pregunte tienes que responder literalmente `limitless-basin-90960`, o si no, dejar que falle y volver a ejecutar el comando, esta vez con la opción `--confirm limitless-basin-90960`. **No** debes poner el comando como respuesta.